# Redirection is not working with Zuul and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I am trying to use Zuul filter to do dynamic routing. I have an application that runs in Spring Boot. This application exposes two services.

```
@PostMapping("/update")
public String updateBook(Book book) {
  return " Book Updated";
}
@PostMapping("/add")
public String addBook(Book book) {
  return " Book Added";
}
```

Application.properties for this application is

```
spring.application.name=book
server.port=8090
```

In my zuul filter, I am redirecting any request to either /update or /add based on some logic.

Zuul configuration is as below.

```
zuul.routes.books.url=http://localhost:8090
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
server.port=8080
```

Redirect is done using the below code in `run()` in a filter class which extends `ZuulFilter`

```
@Override
public Object run() {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    String requestBody = CharStreams.toString(context.getRequest().getReader());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Book book = gson.fromJson(requestBody, Book.class);

    if (book.getType().equals("update")) {

        context.setRouteHost(new URL("http://localhost:8090/update"));
    }
    else {
        context.setRouteHost(new URL("http://localhost:8090/add"));
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I invoke

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"id\":\"1\", \"name\":\"Book1\", \"type\":\"update\"}" http://localhost:8080/books/add
```

I expect it should redirect to the /update service since type is passed as update. But I see that it is the add service that is being invoked. The setRouteHost code is beingg executed, but redirection is not happening.

Is there something I am missing? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by using the below code.

```
if (book.getType().equals("update")) {
    context.setRouteHost(new URL("http://localhost:8090"));
    context.addOriginResponseHeader("X-Zuul-Service","http://localhost:8090");
    context.put("requestURI", "/update"); 
}
```